# Android using image file in an effective way

Tags: android

I am developing an application which displays a lot of image files from the server. I am designing the app to be compatible with all the android devices. I am facing the resolution problem. All the images are of various sizes. I want to know how can I use these images in my app without effecting the resolutions. Any solutions/suggestions?

Comment: how may layout folder have u create in your project

Comment: use Action bar , shape drawable, 9patch images

Comment: Its a shopping app, It displays the product image so 9patch is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your class and give your target height and width

```
            int targetWidth = 500;
            int targetHeight = 300;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();                    
            bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FilePathStrings[position],bmpOptions);
            int currHeight = bmpOptions.outHeight;
               int currWidth = bmpOptions.outWidth;
               int sampleSize =1;
               if (currHeight>targetHeight || currWidth>targetWidth) 
               {
                   if (currWidth>currHeight)
                    sampleSize = Math.round((float)currHeight/(float)targetHeight);
                   else 
                    sampleSize = Math.round((float)currWidth/(float)targetWidth);
               }
               bmpOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
               bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
               bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FilePathStrings[position],bmpOptions);
               imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```